# Not downloading in network drive of particular system?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using below code in service file for auto downloading. It works in my system and our network drive, but when i installed it client pc not working but it download in all folders except server shared location.

```
try
{
    filename = @"N:\Shared\tna related\tna (for processing)\TNA DATA\Timesuite\LOC" + filename + ".csv";
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(filename);
                                       file.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        file.Close();
        TraceImplogs.TraceLTService("Download Completed");

}
catch (Exception es)
{
    TraceImplogs.TraceLTService("error 2"+es.Message);
}
```

Error Shows in client pc:

> Could not find a part of the path 'N:\Shared\tna related\tna (for processing)\TNA DATA\DXB2018-05-12.csv'.

Comment: AFAIK I think mapped drives added for a user on a system not public path for all users in system for this reason you should use UNC path that you may face with other problems.

Comment: can you help this...

Comment: [This link](https://emby.media/community/index.php?/topic/703-how-to-make-unc-folder-shares/) can help you to make UNC shared folder.

Comment: Is this ASP.Net code? That means it's running in a web server right? Can you clarify. What do you mean by "client" when you've posted web server code?